in matlab, is a matrix of condition number of 1e20 definitely more ill-conditioned than a matrix of condition number of 1e19？
I am working with some ill-conditioned matrices, trying to find the relationship between the matrix's ill-conditioning and the results. However, I have noticed that the condition numbers of these matrices are extremely large, with the smallest singular values even smaller than eps. Does this mean that the condition numbers I got might be inaccurate?
